# Single word for 'never return'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for 'never return' or 'will never return'? e.g,

> She's gone and will never return.

Sorry if it's a poor example I'm not a native speaker of the English language. So, if you find any mistake in what I have written, you are free to fix for me or tell me.

Comment: She's gone forever?

Comment: Elvis has left the building. :)

Comment: Kingston Trio, 1962: … (M.T.A. song) Well, did he ever return?
No he never returned and his fate is still unlearned (what a pity)
He may ride forever 'neath the streets of Boston
He's the man who never returned…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your best bet is to modify the "gone." For example, "gone for good" or "gone permanently".

Comment: "She's permanently gone." is actually a little tighter - unless you want to use permanently for affect - such as: "She's gone...permanently." :-)

Answer (score 4):

Consider **[abandon](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/abandon)**

> to give up (something) completely or forever: *to abandon all hope*

Your construction could be *She's abandoned us!*

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the subjects choice in the matter, I could recommend **[exile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exile)**.

> (As a verb) Expel and bar (someone) from their native country, typically for political or punitive reasons

If the person leaving was told to go, you could say *she was exiled*. This implies that she was forced to leave and may not return.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. There are quite a few words that you could use to convey the idea of her having left:

deserted, left, quit, defected, for example.

It's much more difficult to find a single word that conveys the ideas of 'leaving' and 'for good'.

Could any of the following work?

Ditched (us), bailed out (on us), cut loose and run, flown the coop, flown the nest (usually used to indicate children having grown up and left home), walked out on.

The best one-word option I can think of is to see if you can think of a famous literary character, and use her name as a verb. For instance, if you were trying to describe a girl who eloped with a lover, you might say she 'Jessica-d' / 'Jessicaed' / 'Jessica'd' as in Merchant of Venice.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the phrase "for good": She's gone for good.